# How to show the middle element of array in the collection view when the app is launched?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Can Somebody please tell me, How to show the middle element of array in the collection view when the app is launched and other elements are show in the left and right side of this middle element?

[image]

Comment: Can you share some code ?

Comment: Add your required UI image

Comment: i already added the image

Answer (score 1):

In **viewDidLayoutSubviews** method scroll your collection view to that particular IndexPath. And for do it for first time when launch use bool variable.

```
var isFirstTime = true
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if isFirstTime {
        isFirstTime = false
         let selectedIndex = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
          self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: selectedIndex, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(myArr.count/2) inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:NO];`

Change the section in index path accordingly.

Comment: your code crashed my app and it shows "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'attempt to scroll to invalid index path: <NSIndexPath: 0x60000042aaa0> {length = 2, path = 2 - 2}'"

Comment: Make sure you add this after myArr has been initialized with all the necessary elements needed by collection view data source and numberOfItemsInSection data source method returns myArr.count